# I dont locate mysql directory after installation

Tags: 16.04, mysql, directory

I installed mysql-server with apt-get install mysql-server, however directory is not in /etc/mysql

Any solution?

My ubuntu is xenial

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6 * see note below if you get an error
sudo apt install mysql-client-5.6
```